# Java if else statements help please?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to output it so it prints if either num1, num2, num3, num4 or num5 = 999 and stops the scanner input from continuing as it does not with my code.  Hope this makes sense and you can help it would be very appreciated.

```
package a5q4;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Drew
 */
public class A5Q4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;
        int num5;

        System.out.println("Enter different numbers between 1 and 100");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        if (num1 == 999) {
            num2 = 0;
            num3 = 0;
            num4 = 0;
            num5 = 0; 
        }
        else {
            num2 = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (num2 == 999) {
            num3 = 0;
            num4 = 0;
            num5 = 0;
        }  
        else {
            num3 = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (num3 == 999) {
            num4 = 0;
            num5 = 0;   
        }
        else {
            num4 = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (num4 == 999) {
            num5 = 0;   
        }
        else {
            num5 = input.nextInt();
        }
```

Comment: Seems like picking 999 is a weird exit exit condition.  Also, are you able to use loops such as `while` to solve this?

Comment: Nope no loops just started learning thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can *declare* and *initialize* multiple `int`(s) on one line. If I understand your question, you want to test if a given `num` value isn't `999` **and** if it isn't then read the `nextInt`. You'll need to nest your `if`(s) to do it with individual `num` values. Something like,

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0;

System.out.println("Enter different numbers between 1 and 100");
num1 = input.nextInt();
if (num1 != 999) {
    num2 = input.nextInt();
    if (num2 != 999) {
        num3 = input.nextInt();
        if (num3 != 999) {
            num4 = input.nextInt();
            if (num4 != 999) {
                num5 = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without `boolean` negation (`!`), it would have to be in nested `else`(s),

```
System.out.println("Enter different numbers between 1 and 100");
num1 = input.nextInt();
if (num1 == 999) {
} else {
    num2 = input.nextInt();
    if (num2 == 999) {
    } else {
        num3 = input.nextInt();
        if (num3 == 999) {
        } else {
            num4 = input.nextInt();
            if (num4 == 999) {
            } else {
                num5 = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```